# Delphi: Get text from an HTTPS WWW resource

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can I get the text out of https://lehrer-programm-experience.netlify.app/version.txt into a string? I already tried
`s:=IdHTTP.Get('https://lehrer-programm-experience.netlify.app/version.txt');`
but I get this error:

[image: Error dialog showing German text: "SSL.Bibliothek konnte nicht geladen werden."]

It's German: "SSL library couldn't be loaded."

Is there another way to do it or did I made a mistake?

Comment: You need the OpenSSL DLLs for `https` support.

Comment: and where can i get it?

Comment: You can find them [here](https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/).

Comment: i moved the zip to the .exe file location and unzppied it there. Still the same Error. I already tried it with the same link but with http:// but its still now working :/

Comment: Try with [this link](https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/openssl-1.0.2p-i386-win32.zip).

Comment: `http` doesn't work because the server redirects to `https`.

Comment: @Olivier [the fulgan mirror has been retired](https://www.indyproject.org/2020/06/16/openssl-binaries-moved-to-github/). The DLLs are now hosted at https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries

Answer (score 0):

I already found out. I navigate to the website by a TWebBrowser https://lehrer-programm-experience.netlify.app/version.html and then take the text out of the site:

```
NewestVersion := WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.Body.InnerText;
```

Comment: Make sure to check the HTTP status to distinguish a `200` from a `404`.